# how to get cart values in codeigniter for paypal payment

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, frameworks

**I apologize too and i know my codes are really ugly ,How can i get the values on the cart even it is in a bad practice way, I really don't understand. I am new in this integrating paypal payment**

**Paypal Controller**

```
  <?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access 
  allowed');

  require_once(APPPATH . 'libraries/paypal-php-sdk/paypal/rest-api-sdk- 
  php/sample/bootstrap.php'); // require paypal files


  use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
  use PayPal\Api\Payment;
  use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
  use PayPal\Api\Amount;
  use PayPal\Api\PaymentExecution;
  use PayPal\Api\RefundRequest;
  use PayPal\Api\Sale;

 class Paypal extends CI_Controller
 {
 public $_api_context;

 function  __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('paypal_model', 'paypal');
    // paypal credentials
    $this->config->load('paypal');

    $this->_api_context = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
        new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
            $this->config->item('client_id'), $this->config- 
    >item('secret')
        )
    );
   }

 function index(){
    $this->load->view('content/payment_credit_form');
}


 function create_payment_with_paypal()
  {

    // setup PayPal api context
    $this->_api_context->setConfig($this->config->item('settings'));


  // ### Payer
 // A resource representing a Payer that funds a payment
 // For direct credit card payments, set payment method
 // to 'credit_card' and add an array of funding instruments.

    $payer['payment_method'] = 'paypal';

    // ### Itemized information
    // (Optional) Lets you specify item wise
  // information
    $item1["name"] = $this->input->post('item_name');
    $item1["sku"] = $this->input->post('item_number');  // Similar to 
   `item_number` in Classic API
    $item1["description"] = $this->input->post('item_description');
    $item1["currency"] ="USD";
    $item1["quantity"] =1;
    $item1["price"] = $this->input->post('item_price');

    $itemList = new ItemList();
    $itemList->setItems(array($item1));

     // ### Additional payment details
     // Use this optional field to set additional
     // payment information such as tax, shipping
    // charges etc.
    $details['tax'] = $this->input->post('details_tax');
    $details['subtotal'] = $this->input->post('details_subtotal');
    // ### Amount
    // Lets you specify a payment amount.
    // You can also specify additional details
    // such as shipping, tax.
    $amount['currency'] = "USD";
    $amount['total'] = $details['tax'] + $details['subtotal'];
    $amount['details'] = $details;
     // ### Transaction
    // A transaction defines the contract of a
     // payment - what is the payment for and who
    // is fulfilling it.
    $transaction['description'] ='Payment description';
    $transaction['amount'] = $amount;
    $transaction['invoice_number'] = uniqid();
    $transaction['item_list'] = $itemList;

    // ### Redirect urls
    // Set the urls that the buyer must be redirected to after
    // payment approval/ cancellation.
    $baseUrl = base_url();
    $redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
    $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl($baseUrl."paypal/getPaymentStatus")
        ->setCancelUrl($baseUrl."paypal/getPaymentStatus");

    // ### Payment
    // A Payment Resource; create one using
     // the above types and intent set to sale 'sale'
    $payment = new Payment();
    $payment->setIntent("sale")
        ->setPayer($payer)
        ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
        ->setTransactions(array($transaction));

    try {
        $payment->create($this->_api_context);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        // NOTE: PLEASE DO NOT USE RESULTPRINTER CLASS IN YOUR ORIGINAL 
     CODE. FOR SAMPLE ONLY
        ResultPrinter::printError("Created Payment Using PayPal. Please 
      visit the URL to Approve.", "Payment", null, $ex);
        exit(1);
    }
    foreach($payment->getLinks() as $link) {
        if($link->getRel() == 'approval_url') {
            $redirect_url = $link->getHref();
            break;
        }
     }

    if(isset($redirect_url)) {
        /** redirect to paypal **/
        redirect($redirect_url);
    }

    $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg','Unknown error 
    occurred');
    redirect('paypal/index');

    }


    public function getPaymentStatus()
    {

    // paypal credentials

    /** Get the payment ID before session clear **/
    $payment_id = $this->input->get("paymentId") ;
    $PayerID = $this->input->get("PayerID") ;
    $token = $this->input->get("token") ;
    /** clear the session payment ID **/

    if (empty($PayerID) || empty($token)) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg','Payment failed');
        redirect('paypal/index');
    }

    $payment = Payment::get($payment_id,$this->_api_context);


    /** PaymentExecution object includes information necessary **/
    /** to execute a PayPal account payment. **/
    /** The payer_id is added to the request query parameters **/
    /** when the user is redirected from paypal back to your site **/
    $execution = new PaymentExecution();
    $execution->setPayerId($this->input->get('PayerID'));

    /**Execute the payment **/
    $result = $payment->execute($execution,$this->_api_context);



    //  DEBUG RESULT, remove it later **/
    if ($result->getState() == 'approved') {
        $trans = $result->getTransactions();

        // item info
        $Subtotal = $trans[0]->getAmount()->getDetails()- 
     >getSubtotal();
        $Tax = $trans[0]->getAmount()->getDetails()->getTax();

        $payer = $result->getPayer();
        // payer info //
        $PaymentMethod =$payer->getPaymentMethod();
        $PayerStatus =$payer->getStatus();
        $PayerMail =$payer->getPayerInfo()->getEmail();

        $relatedResources = $trans[0]->getRelatedResources();
        $sale = $relatedResources[0]->getSale();
        // sale info //
        $saleId = $sale->getId();
        $CreateTime = $sale->getCreateTime();
        $UpdateTime = $sale->getUpdateTime();
        $State = $sale->getState();
        $Total = $sale->getAmount()->getTotal();
        /** it's all right **/
        /** Here Write your database logic like that insert record or 
        value in database if you want **/
        $this->paypal- 

      >create($Total,$Subtotal,$Tax,$PaymentMethod,
      $PayerStatus,$PayerMail,$saleI 
         d,$CreateTime,$UpdateTime,$State);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg','Payment success');
        redirect('paypal/success');
    }
    $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg','Payment failed');
    redirect('paypal/cancel');
   }
   function success(){
    $this->load->view("content/success");
  }
  function cancel(){
    $this->load->view("content/cancel");
   }

   function load_refund_form(){
    $this->load->view('content/Refund_payment_form');
    }

     function refund_payment(){
    $refund_amount = $this->input->post('refund_amount');
    $saleId = $this->input->post('sale_id');
    $paymentValue =  (string) round($refund_amount,2); ;

       // ### Refund amount
      // and refunded fee (to Payee). Use the $amt->details
     // field to mention fees refund details.
    $amt = new Amount();
    $amt->setCurrency('USD')
        ->setTotal($paymentValue);

     // ### Refund object
     $refundRequest = new RefundRequest();
     $refundRequest->setAmount($amt);

      // ###Sale
      // A sale transaction.
      // Create a Sale object with the
     // given sale transaction id.
    $sale = new Sale();
    $sale->setId($saleId);
    try {
        // Refund the sale
        // (See bootstrap.php for more on `ApiContext`)
        $refundedSale = $sale->refundSale($refundRequest, $this- 
         >_api_context);
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
        // NOTE: PLEASE DO NOT USE RESULTPRINTER CLASS IN YOUR ORIGINAL 
        CODE. FOR SAMPLE ONLY
        ResultPrinter::printError("Refund Sale", "Sale", null, 
        $refundRequest, $ex);
        exit(1);
      }


    ResultPrinter::printResult("Refund Sale", "Sale", $refundedSale- 
     >getId(), $refundRequest, $refundedSale);

    return $refundedSale;
      }
       }
```

**Shopping Cart Controller**

```
<?php
```

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

```
   class Shopping_cart extends CI_Controller {


  function index()
  {

   $this->load->model("shopping_cart_model");
   $data["product"] = $this->shopping_cart_model->fetch_all();
  $data["daterange"] = $this- 
  >getDatesFromRange($_SESSION["profile_data"] 
  ['startdate'],$_SESSION["profile_data"]['enddate']);
   $this->load->library('cart');
   $this->load->view("shopping_cart", $data);


   if (isset($_POST['submitbtn'])){
   foreach($this->cart->contents() as $items)
    {
    $status = "ON-GOING";    
    $data = array(

    "product_name"   => $items["name"],
    "quantity"       => $items["qty"],
    "product_price"  => $items["price"],
    "username" => $_SESSION["profile_data"]["username"],
    'mobilenum' => $_SESSION["profile_data"]['mobilenum'],
    'homeadd' => $_SESSION["profile_data"]['homeadd'],
    'startdate' => $_SESSION["profile_data"]['startdate'],
    'enddate' => $_SESSION["profile_data"]['enddate'],
    'place_type' => $_SESSION["profile_data"]['place_type'],
    'time' => $_SESSION["profile_data"]['time'],
    'status' => $status,
    'total' => $items["subtotal"],


  );
  $this->db->insert('occasion', $data);
  $this->session->set_flashdata("success", "You successfully been 
  reserved");
   redirect("shopping_cart","refresh");

    }

    }       


   }

  function add()
  {
  $this->load->library("cart");
   $data = array(
   "id"  => $_POST["product_id"],
   "name"  => $_POST["product_name"],
    "qty"  => $_POST["quantity"],
   "price"  => $_POST["product_price"],
   "place_type" => $_SESSION["profile_data"]['place_type']

  );
 $this->cart->insert($data); //return rowid 
 echo $this->view();
  }

 function load()
  {
 echo $this->view();
  }

 function remove()
  {
  $this->load->library("cart");
 $row_id = $_POST["row_id"];
   $data = array(
  'rowid'  => $row_id,
  'qty'  => 0
   );
$this->cart->update($data);
   echo $this->view();
   }

 function clear()
  {
 $this->load->library("cart");
  $this->cart->destroy();
  echo $this->view();
  }

 function getDatesFromRange($start, $end, $format='Y-m-d') {
    return array_map(function($timestamp) use($format) {
        return date($format, $timestamp);
    },
    range(strtotime($start) + ($start < $end ? 4000 : 8000), 
    strtotime($end) + ($start < $end ? 8000 : 4000), 86400));
 }

function view()
 {
 $this->load->library("cart");
 $output = '';
 $output .= '
<h3>Rental Carts</h3><br />
 <div class="table-responsive">
 <div align="right">
<button type="button" id="clear_cart" class="btn btn-warning">Clear 
 Cart</button>
 </div>
  <br />
  <table class="table table-bordered">
 <tr>
 <th width="40%">Name</th>
 <th width="15%">Quantity</th>
 <th width="15%">Price</th>
 <th width="15%">Total</th>
 <th width="15%">Action</th>
 </tr>

 ';
  $count = 0;
 foreach($this->cart->contents() as $items)
  {
 $count++;
  $output .='

<tr> 
<td>'.$items["name"].' <input type="hidden" id="cart_name" 
name="cart_name" value="'.$items["name"].'" /></td>
<td>'.$items["qty"].' <input type="hidden" id="cart_qty" 
 name="cart_qty" value="'.$items["qty"].'" /></td>
<td>'.$items["price"].' <input type="hidden" id="cart_price" 
 name="cart_price" value="'.$items["price"].'" /></td>
<td>'.$items["subtotal"].'</td> 

<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs 
 remove_inventory" id="'.$items["rowid"].'">Remove</button></td>
   </tr>
   ';
  }
   $output .= '
    <tr>
   <td colspan="4" align="right">Total</td>
   <td>'.$this->cart->total().'</td>
  </tr>
  </table>

   </div>
   ';

  if($count == 0)
   {
   $output = '<h3 align="center">Cart is Empty</h3>';

   }
    return $output;
     }
     }
```

**ShoppingCartView**

```
 <h3 align="center">AOZ RESERVATION PRODUCTS RENTALS</h3>

<?php if (isset($_SESSION['success'])) { ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success"> <?php echo $_SESSION['success']; 
   ?></div>
<?php  } ?>

<form action="" method="POST">

<?php
    $numItems = count($product);
    $i = 0;
    foreach($product as $row) {
    $i++;
     ?>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url().'images/'.$row- 
             >product_image; ?>"
                 class="img-thumbnail" 
                 alt="<?php echo $row->product_name; ?>"
                 style="max-width: 300px;" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
            <h4><?php echo $row->product_name; ?></h4>
            <p>Description:&nbsp<?php echo $row->description; ?></p>


            <h3 class="text-danger"><?php echo $row->product_price; ?> 
            PHP</h3>

            <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control 
          quantity" id="<?php echo $row->product_id; ?>" /><br />

            <input type="button" name="add_cart" 
                    class="btn btn-success add_cart" 
                    data-productname="<?php echo $row->product_name; ? 
                >" 
                    data-price="<?php echo $row->product_price; ?>" 
                    data-productid="<?php echo  $row->product_id; ?>" 
                    value="Add to Reserve"
            />
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>

   <?php if($i != $numItems){ ?>
      <hr style="width: 80%;" />
    <?php } ?>



   <?php } ?>   

   <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
    <div id="cart_details">
        <h3 align="center">Cart is Empty</h3>
    </div>
    <button id="submitbtn" name="submitbtn" style="display:none;" 
  class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
   </div>    

   </form>    

<script src="<?php echo base_url().'assests/jquery/jquery- 
  3.1.0.min.js'; ?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo 
 base_url().'assests/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js'; ?>"></script>

 </body>
</html>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

  $('.add_cart').click(function(){
  var product_id = $(this).data("productid");
  var product_name = $(this).data("productname");
  var product_price = $(this).data("price");
  var daterange = <?php echo json_encode(count($daterange));?>;
   var quantity = $('#' + product_id).val();
  if(quantity != '' && quantity > 0)
  {
  $.ajax({
  url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/shopping_cart/add",
   method:"POST",
 data:{product_id:product_id, product_name:product_name, 
  product_price:product_price * daterange, quantity:quantity},
   success:function(data)
   {
   // alert("Product Added into Cart");
   $('#cart_details').html(data);
   $('#' + product_id).val('');
   $("#submitbtn").css("display", "block");
   }
   });
  }
  else
  {
  alert("Please Enter quantity");
 }
  });

 $('#cart_details').load("<?php echo base_url(); ? 
>index.php/shopping_cart/load");

 $(document).on('click', '.remove_inventory', function(){
 var row_id = $(this).attr("id");
  if(confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this?"))
  {
  $.ajax({
  url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/shopping_cart/remove",
   method:"POST",
   data:{row_id:row_id},
  success:function(data)
  {
 alert("Product removed from Cart");
 $('#cart_details').html(data);
  }
  });
 }
 else
 {
 return false;
  }
  });

 $(document).on('click', '#clear_cart', function(){
  if(confirm("Are you sure you want to clear cart?"))
   {
  $.ajax({
    url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/shopping_cart/clear",
     success:function(data)
     {
      alert("Your cart has been clear...");
     $('#cart_details').html(data);
      }
       });
        }
    else
       {
    return false;
        }
    });

       });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're working with [PayPal Payments Standard](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/pps_integration/) here, which means you would need to add the [individual item variables](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#individual-items-variables) for line items.

That should work fine for you, but if you want more freedom and flexibility with your integration in general you'll want to switch to the checkout APIs instead of using PayPal Standard.

We have a [PHP SDK for PayPal](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) that makes this very simple.  You can install it into CodeIgniter using Composer, and it includes samples and template scripts for every API call PayPal offers.  You just fill in the values for any call you're working with and it does the rest.